# How to resolve object overlap in vr mode in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am making a solar system vr game. In which the planet Saturn ring feels in front of the planet on android device as shown in screen shot but in unity editor it shown perfect (means Planet shows in middle of the ring).

My camera near and for clipping planes are 0.03 and 1200 respectively. How to resolve such types of problem ?[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you increase the near value to 1, what happens? Any shader variants to the material used which are different on Android than on PC?

Comment: My guess is that it's a depth buffer problem. Maybe try this fix : https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/334

Comment: Ah yes, if you go to PlayerSettings and then under "Resolution and Presentation" for your Android settings, is "Disable Depth and Stencil" selected? Uncheck that if so.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your quick reply. I will try that.. :)